# how to get next string at the end of the line when string matched

Tags: regex

I am reading PDF file. in one page of PDF file i want to get the date from this string line "Illustration as of : December 9, 2016". i am able to search the "Illustration as of :" using regex. but how i cant get the date. i need to return the in regex result. i don't need to return the same string that i am search.

```
i tried this but it only return me Illustration as of :

const regex = /Illustration as of:/g;
const str = `Illustration as of: December 9, 2016`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

i just need to return this result December 9, 2016

Comment: `(?:Illustration as of:\s?)(January|February|March|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{1,2},\s?\d{4}` or `(?:Illustration as of:\s?).+$`

Comment: its look like very complicated..

Comment: The second one is pretty simple, just look for `Illustraton as of:` and take everything after it until the end of the line.

Comment: Please vote for second one from my side. i have not enough reputation to vote it. your vote will help others to use this answer.

Comment: how i make it answer of my question...?

Comment: your second one not return the date. it return complete string. see below.
Match 1
Full match 0-36 `Illustration as of: December 9, 2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const regex = /Illustration as of:+([^\n]+)/g;
```

try this one i hope it will return u just date. it will return u end of the string after match.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:Illustration as of:\s?)(January|February|March|May|June|July|August|Septembe‌​r|October|November|D‌​ecember) \d{1,2},\s?\d{4}` or `(?:Illustration as of:\s?).+$`